# Is .Net 6 also called .NetFramework version 6? and is it not compatible with .netcoreapp2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core

We are trying to upgrade our .Net core 2.1 app to use .Net 6. I used tried to use the upgrade assistant here, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant/tutorial/install-upgrade-assistant

1. We now get many errors but the one that is confusing me is the naming, Is **.NetFramework,Version 6.0** the same a .Net 6? I thought framework was old stuff?
2. Also as you can see from the error example below, it seems that our current nuget packages are not compatible with the new code, if I have read that right. Should we have set the nuget packages to be .Net Standard 2.1 to get around this?

[image]

Comment: Tends to show up when the installed SDK is old and doesn't know what "net60" means.  Current version [is 6.0.403](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

Comment: .NET6 (and beyond) is .NET Core 6.  .NET Framework ended at 4.8.1.  If you have nuget packages that are incompatible, then you will need to find replacements.

Comment: So seems that the upgrade assistant in the link is not for going from .net core 2.1 to .net 6 then!

Comment: That error looks like the Nuget package targets .NET Core 2. If you want the package to work across versions it should target .NET Standard or have multiple targets for each .NET version.

Comment: The way TFMs are parsed, `net60` and `net6.0` are different things. Without the dot, it's parsed as .NET Framework, and that version doesn't exist (`net481` is the latest: notice that it's not "net4.8.1"). With the dot, it's parsed correctly as .NET [Core] (.NETCoreApp). I'm guessing your project file's `TargetFramework`(`s`) element is missing the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I should not have tried to use the upgrade assistant, that seems to be for framework relates code. Instead following steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio for each version. Not ideal as would like an easier solution, but at least it gives some guidelines.